# How especiy file types cache broweser in my website

Tags: caching, browser

Hello everybody I'm looking for how to especify browser cache time for files (especially images) in my web. But I'm confused about how to do it and what's the better practice about that.

Anybody could help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has same problem I resolved it using .htaccess from html5-boilerplate ;)